# Using loops in backbone/underscore's templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone.js/underscore.js template that I am feeding into a backbone view for rendering. The View is passed a model that contains an array `posts` of objects (which I call `post` in the template).

**Problem**: When I try to loop through all the elements of the array `posts`, I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` and refers a line in the backbone View's code `template: _.template( $('#tpl_SetView').html() )`.

Am I doing the loop incorrectly which is causing this error?

**Template code**

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_SetView">
    <div class="row_4">
        <div class="photo_container">
            <div class="set_cover">
                <img src="/<%= posts[0].thumb_subpath %><%= posts[0].img_filename %>" width=240 />
            </div>
            <div class="set_thumbs">
                <%= _.each(posts, function(post) { %>
                    <img src="<%= post.thumb_subpath %><%= posts.img_filename %>" width=55 />
                <%= }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I think it is better to organize the code to new models and views. Looping through templates in not good practice

Comment: I'm curious why you think looping through a template is bad practice.  I just implemented the answer shown by James Woodruff below for the use of building a list of select options (which vary depending on the situation) and it seems to me a lot easier to just loop through the array of options rather than making a separate view called 'selectOption' or whatever and then iteratively appending it to the <select>.  is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To echo a variable use `<%= %>`, but to parse javaScript code, just use `<% %>`.

For example:

```
// In your Backbone View
var posts = {"posts": this.model.toJSON()};
var template = _.template($("#tpl_SetView").html(), posts);


// In your template
<div class="row_4">
    <div class="photo_container">
        <div class="set_cover">
            <img src="/<%= _.escape(posts[0].thumb_subpath) %><%= _.escape(posts[0].img_filename) %>" width=240 />
        </div>
    <div class="set_thumbs">
        <% _.each(posts, function(post){ %>
            <img src="<%= _.escape(post.thumb_subpath) %><%= _.escape(posts.img_filename) %>" width=55 />
        <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find that the problem  is in these lines:

```js
<%= _.each(posts, function(post) { %>
    <img src="<%= post.thumb_subpath %><%= posts.img_filename %>" width=55 />
<%= }); %>
```

From my recollection of what underscore does to evaluate templates, these lines don't make much sense.  <strike>Each <%=..%> item is evaluated separately.. that is, they must be full evaluatable expressions, not partial function blocks..</strike>

Edit:  Actually, James is right.  <%..%> can be defined separately (it all comes down to a big javascript string in the end).  It is escaped and the interpolated expressions that must be separate expressions.

Edit II:  Even so, in the evaluation context I think the use of the function block would still possibly create a bizzare javascript string that might not evaluate quite as intended... I'd have to think about it. It might still work out totally fine.