# Escaping underscore template syntax in twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, underscore.js

I have a .twig file with some content that is rendered using backbone via underscore's template engine.

**index.twig file**

```
<select name="" id="" class='select-specializations'>
    <% _.each(itemList, function(item){%>
    <option value="<%= item %>"> <%= item %> </option>
    <%})%>
</select>
```

The problem is that twig doesn't seem to ignore this `<%` syntax when I `autoescape` in my template file. Throwing the following error:

> A block must start with a tag name in..

And if I use the `raw` block, underscore doesn't seem to undestand the syntax. Is there a was to resolve this conflict of syntaxes between twig and underscore?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780974/using-loops-in-backbone-underscores-templates

Comment: If you want Underscore to parse it, why have it as a `twig` template?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski The html page is generated using symphony.

Comment: @CarrieKendall How is that question relevant to mine?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as Andrew mentioned. The solution is to escape the underscore template tags. Below is the final code after escaping.

```
<select name="" id="" class='select-specializations'>
    {{ "<% _.each(itemList, function(item){%>" }}
    <option value="{{ "<%= item %>" }}"> {{ "<%= item %>" }} </option>
    {{ "<%})%>" }}
</select>
```

You will find more info from [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#escaping)

Answer (score -1):

Surround your underscore code with verbatim. 
See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html for details.

Side note: `<%` is not the problem, but `{%` is.

Comment: Its the same as the raw tag. Unfortunately I tried it and din't work